# Does `flutter buid apk` produces `armeabi-v7a` compatible apk?

Tags: flutter

Does this variants produces the same apk? The second does not work on emulator. As far as I know the `android-arm` produces `armeabi-v7a` and the second command also targets `v7a` is not it?

> flutter build apk

vs

> flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm

Answer (score 0):

The `flutter build apk` command results in a fat APK which include support for armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, and x86_64.

In the [Build an APK](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#build-an-apk) section from the docs, it says:

> Removing the --split-per-abi flag results in a fat APK that contains your code compiled for all the target ABIs.

"All the target ABIs" refers to the ABIs mentioned before, which are:

> [project]/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-**armeabi-v7a**-release.apk
> [project]/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-**arm64-v8a**-release.apk
> [project]/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-**x86_64**-release.apk